# How do I add an image to a progress bar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, progress

I'm basically trying to set up a progress bar in HTML and CSS with JSFiddle for a website. I want to overlay an image over the bar that can move with the bar until it reaches the goal, however I cannot figure out how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.96);
    text-align: center;
}
#progressbar {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
}
#progressbar > div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 30%;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.text {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

  <h1>Help Mr. Finley get to the finish line!</h1>

  <div class="box">
      <div id="progressbar">
          <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Marching... 30%</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ProgressBars/

Comment: How do I upvote a comment? I can only see how to do that with answers.

Comment: Ah I see, it won't let me upvote because I have not reached a reputation of 15 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3urw5wy/

Add in `background-image:url(AddImageUrlHere)` to replace `background-color: #fff;` as below:

```
#progressbar > div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image:url(http://upstreamonline.com.cdn.bitbit.net/incoming/article1250137.ece/alternates/article_main/Cross%20the%20line%20sprint%20finishing%20tape%20runner%20athletics.jpg);
    width: 30%;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tested it out and it is working great! I just am now fiddling with the picture I need in photoshop and adjusting the height. When I am ready to deploy this code for the website that it's for, and since it has to be HTML, I can just do  `<style type=CSS> 
CSS CODE
</style>` in order to allow the CSS to work, right? Thank you again so much for your help.

Comment: Also, how would I go about adding progress intervals under the bar at the beginning, middle, and end? Thanks!

Comment: yes I can imagine a lot of fiddling with image in photoshop! no need to specify the type `<style>css here </style>` will work just fine. If you are happy with the answer please mark it as correct :) With the intervals you should start a new stackoverflow question - give me the link here and I'll see if I can help

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help, here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086674/how-do-i-add-intervals-to-a-progress-bar